# Can MarkLogic pull data from Oracle or SQL Server?

Tags: marklogic

Does MarkLogic or MarkLogic Data Hub provide any inbuilt mechanism to connect to Oracle or SQL Server? My ask is to periodically pull data from Oracle and SQL Server databases and insert into MarkLogic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875291/is-it-possible-to-import-data-from-sql-to-marklogic/56875560#56875560

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to import data from SQL to MarkLogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875291/is-it-possible-to-import-data-from-sql-to-marklogic)